# Image behind the text using wrapfig

Tags: wrapfig

i have a main.Tex file. In main there are text subfiles.

```
\subfile{Pregunta1.tex}
\subfile{Pregunta2.tex} 
\subfile{Pregunta3.tex}
\subfile{Pregunta4.tex}
```

I want to put an image surrounded by text in the subfiles. The issue is, there is written this in subfile Pregunta2.tex:

```
...se puede hacer conectándolo a la simulación; esto se denomina \textit{Hardware-in-the-loop} (\textbf{HIL}).\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{.3\textwidth}
  \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.27\textwidth]{images/RTHIL.jpg}
  \caption{This is the image.}
\end{wrapfigure}

\textbf{Las simulaciones eléctricas en tiempo real con HIL tienen muchas ventajas.} Una de ellas es que, para...
```

When i press recompile (in overleaf) with subfile open everything is ok (but only compiles that subfile).
[image]
But trying to recompile from the main open (so it shows all the document), happens that the image is behind the text.
[image]

I am using overleaf.

if someone can help me, would appreciate that.
Sorry about my grammar, hope could be understood.

Best regards

Comment: presumbly the code following the wrapfig that you have not shown is preventing wrapping, please show a small complete example

Comment: Please try to give us an MWE (Minimal Working Example) we can copy-paste-compile to reproduce the problem. We can't do that with just fragments, so all anybody can do is try to guess.

Comment: you have changed the question to be about subfile. you still have provided no example sorry impossible to guess unless you show an example. compare with my answer which has two complete examples

Answer (score 1):

You provided no example but I guess you have

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}



\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{.3\textwidth}
  \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.27\textwidth]{example-image}
  \caption{This is the image.}
\end{wrapfigure}
{\bfseries Bold text bold text} normal text normal text normal text
 normal text normal text normal text normal text normal text normal text
 normal text normal text normal text normal text normal text normal text
 normal text normal text normal text normal text normal text normal text
 normal text normal text normal text normal text normal text normal text
 normal text normal text normal text normal text normal text normal text.

\end{document}
```

You can not start the text inside a group, `\textbf` starts the paragraph earlier:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}



\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{.3\textwidth}
  \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.27\textwidth]{example-image}
  \caption{This is the image.}
\end{wrapfigure}
\textbf{Bold text bold text} normal text normal text normal text
 normal text normal text normal text normal text normal text normal text
 normal text normal text normal text normal text normal text normal text
 normal text normal text normal text normal text normal text normal text
 normal text normal text normal text normal text normal text normal text
 normal text normal text normal text normal text normal text normal text.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, i provided more information to the question. If you can have a look on that again would be great. Thank u for your time